# Passing a query output as input to in clause for another query in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have 2 tables (say `Student` and `College`) and a third table (`StudentCollege`), which has `student_id` and `college_id` foreign keys.

I want to give output from below query:

```py
list = (
    db.session.query(StudentCollegeModel.College_id)
    .filter(StudentCollegeModel.student_id== student_id)
    .all()
)
```

to below query:

```py
(
    db.session.query(CollegeModel)
    .filter(CollegeModel.College_id.in_(list))
    .all()
)
```

But its giving programming error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first query returns a list of named tuples. You need to convert it to a list. For example:

```
college_tuples = db.session.query(StudentCollegeModel.College_id).filter(StudentCollegeModel.student_id == student_id).all()
college_id_list = [r.College_id for r in college_tuples]
db.session.query(CollegeModel.filter(CollegeModel.College_id.in_(college_id_list)).all()
```

Here we fetch your college id tuples, flatten it and used the flattened version to preform your second query.

Answer (score 10):

You don't need to execute the first query to use it as a subquery in the second. This saves you from having to construct an in memory list of all of the `College_id`'s before making the `in_()` query and means that you only make one round trip to the database.

```py
subquery = (
    db.session.query(StudentCollegeModel.College_id)
    .filter(StudentCollegeModel.student_id== student_id)
)

result = (
    db.session.query(CollegeModel)
    .filter(CollegeModel.College_id.in_(subquery))
    .all()
)
```

Comment: This is a very important point and should be the accepted answer. Whenever you add no extra complexity and make a better performing statement, you should go with it.

Answer (score 0):

Similar as follows:

```
cs = StudentCollegeModel.query.filter_by(student_id=student_id).distinct('college_id').entities_with('college_id', flat=True).all()
CollegeModel.query.filter(CollegeModel.College_id.in_(cs)).all()
```